# Dynamically remove dart tags based on first tag size

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, dart, google-dfp

I have a page that has 5 ads:
- 728 & 214 ads in header (side by side)
- 350 ad in rail
- 728 & 214 ads in footer (side by side)

The 728 and 214 are side by side on the page in the respective positions. We have some sponsors with 970 ads and so now we have to make a change to the display.

The change is: 
- for each 728 ad (which can also load the 970 size) check the ad response and if the ad is 970, we want to remove the 214 ad call.

The display works perfectly if I do not remove the 214 dart div and just hide it ".hide()". But this doesn't work because we don't want to make the ad call for the 214 if a 970 ad is returned. However, when I do a ".remove()" of the first 214 ad, no other ad on the page get's rendered or even called for that matter.

What am I doing that is causing all of the other ad calls to not be made? Is there a better way to do this? Here is my code:

```
var wideAdWidth = 970,
wideAdClass = "wide970",
dfpMetaDataAttributeName = 'data-admeta-dfp',
firstAdLoaded = false;

function checkForWideAd(wideAdDivId, shortAdDivId) {
 // Get ad info from returned data
 var ad_data_string = $(wideAdDivId + ' .GoogleActiveViewClass').attr(dfpMetaDataAttributeName);

 if(typeof ad_data_string !== 'undefined') {
  var ad_data = ad_data_string.split(',');
  var ad_width = ad_data[1];
  if(ad_width == wideAdWidth) {
    $(shortAdDivId).remove();
    $(wideAdDivId).addClass(wideAdClass);
  }

  firstAdLoaded = true;
 }
}

//If the width of the ad being loaded into the top is 970px, hide the 214 ad.
$('#dart-tag0').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
  checkForWideAd('#dart-tag0', '#dart-tag1');
});
```

Here's what's in the 214x90 div (the definition for the ad):

Drupal.DART.settings.loadLastTags['dart_tag1'] = '{"machinename":"dart_tag1","name":"Top 214x90","pos":"7","sz":"214x90","active":"1","block":"1","settings":{"overrides":{"site":"","zone":"","slug":""},"options":{"scriptless":0,"method":"adj"},"key_vals":[{"key":"tile","val":"7","eval":0}]},"table":"dart_tags","type":"Normal","export_type":1,"key_vals":{"!c":[{"val":"home","eval":false}],"genre":[{"val":"sports","eval":false}],"tandomad":[{"val":"eTandomAd","eval":true}],"sect":[{"val":"home","eval":false}],"pos":[{"val":"7","eval":false}],"sz":[{"val":"214x90","eval":false}],"site":[{"val":"mydomain","eval":0}],"tile":[{"val":"7","eval":0}],"ord":[{"val":"ord","eval":true}]},"prefix":"test","site":"mydomain","zone":"mydomain_home","slug":"","network_id":"myid","noscript":{"src":"http://ad.doubleclick.net/myid/ad/test.mydomain/mydomain_home;!c=home;genre=type;sect=home;pos=7;sz=214x90;site=mydomain;tile=7;ord=2405589736?","href":"http://ad.doubleclick.net/myid/jump/test.mydomain/mydomain_home;!c=home;genre=sports;sect=home;pos=7;sz=214x90;site=mydomain;tile=7;ord=2405589736?"}}';

Comment: I can only guess here. But maybe the first .remove() call removes some other javascript code that loads additional ads?

Comment: I had that theory also. The only thing in the div is the array definition for the dart tag.